# Authorizing a non admin user to run Admin SDK in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

I'd like to allow a non admin user in our domain to be able to use a Google Sheet which is running code to:

- List some groups in our organisation
- Delete/Add users

This requires admin rights, so the following code will not run in a non-admin account... How is it possibile to authorise the non admin user to run admin code?

```
var RatatoskSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

// -- ADD USER TO GROUP -- Set trigger to onedit -- //
function addUsertoGroup(e) {

   var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
   if (sheet.getName() === 'AddUser') { //Hinders edits on other sheets

      var userData = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('AddUser');
      var userEmail = userData.getRange(2, 1).getValue(); //Gets data from AddUser.A2
      var groupId = userData.getRange(2, 2).getValue(); //Gets data from cell B2

      var newMember = {
         email: userEmail,
         role: "MEMBER"
      };


      AdminDirectory.Members.insert(newMember, groupId); // Adds new member to a Google group
      var groupData = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('GroupAddress');
      var groupTwo = [userEmail, groupId]
      groupData.appendRow(groupTwo); //Add member and group to GroupAddress
      var header = ['UserEmail', 'GroupID'];
      userData.clear(); //Reset AddUser (Delete all)
      userData.appendRow(header).setFrozenRows(1);



   }
}

// -- REMOVE USER FROM GROUP -- Set trigger of this function to onedit -- //
function deleteGroupMember(e) {

   var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
   if (sheet.getName() === 'RemoveUser') { //Hinders edits on other sheets

      var RemoveUserData = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('RemoveUser');
      var groupData = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('GroupAddress');

      var userEmail = RemoveUserData.getRange(2, 1).getValue(); //Gets data from RemoveUser.A2
      var groupId = RemoveUserData.getRange(2, 2).getValue(); //Gets data from  RemoveUser.B2

      AdminDirectory.Members.remove(groupId, userEmail); //Removes member from a Google group

      var removeDataValues = RemoveUserData.getDataRange().getValues();
      var groupDataValues = groupData.getDataRange().getValues();
      var resultArray = [];
      for (var n in groupDataValues) { //
         var keep = true
         for (var p in removeDataValues) {
            if (groupDataValues[n][0] == removeDataValues[p][0] && groupDataValues[n][1] == removeDataValues[p][1]) {
               keep = false;
               break;
            }
         }
         if (keep) {
            resultArray.push(groupDataValues[n])
         };
      }


      var start = 2; //Starts from Row 2          //
      var killTheRows = groupData.getLastRow() - start + 1; //                           // These lines deletes all rows in GroupAddress
      groupData.deleteRows(start, killTheRows); //Delete all rows with values//

      groupData.getRange(2, 1, resultArray.length, resultArray[0].length).setValues(resultArray); //Repopulate the rows in GroupAddress

      var header = ['UserEmail', 'GroupID'];
      RemoveUserData.clear();
      RemoveUserData.appendRow(header).setFrozenRows(1);



   }
}

// -- LISTS ALL GROUPS AND USERS WITHIN THEM -- Set this as a timed trigger to error correct once a day -- //
function listAllGroups() {
   var grouprows = [];
   var pageToken;

   var page;
   do {
      page = AdminDirectory.Groups.list({
         domain: 'THEDOMAIN',
         maxResults: 200,
         pageToken: pageToken
      });
      var groups = page.groups;
      if (groups) {
         for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
            var group = groups[i];
            if (group.email.substring(0, 5) === "staff") {
               grouprows.push(group.email);
            }
         }
      }
      pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
   } while (pageToken);

   var rows = [];
   var pageToken, page2;
   for (var j = 0; j < grouprows.length; j++) {
      do {
         page2 = AdminDirectory.Members.list(grouprows[j], {
            domainName: 'YOURDOMAIN',
            maxResults: 500,
            pageToken: pageToken,
         });
         var members = page2.members;
         if (members) {
            for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
               var member = members[i];
               var row = [member.email, grouprows[j]];
               rows.push(row);
            }
         }
         pageToken = page2.nextPageToken;
      } while (pageToken);
      if (rows.length > 1) {
         var groupData = RatatoskSheet.getSheetByName("GroupAddress");
         var header = ['UserEmail', 'GroupID'];
         groupData.clear();
         groupData.appendRow(header).setFrozenRows(1);
         groupData.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, header.length).setValues(rows);

      }

   }
   groupData.deleteRow(2); //NB! Removes first group(all@yourdomain.com) Make this whole line a comment if unsure. 



}
```

Comment: This can be possible using [Service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts)

Comment: Hello, it looks like this is not part of the Google Workspace for Education platform. Correct?

Comment: No it will be applicable to All platforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A way to achieve this is by creating a service account and using domain wide delegation of authority.**

After that, since you want to continue on using Apps Script, you will have to get the access token for this service account and make the request using `UrlFetchApp` since you cannot pass an access token while making a request using Admin SDK Directory advanced service.

Therefore, the requests will end up looking something similar to:

```
var options = {
    method: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json",
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/{groupKey}/members', {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
    }
  });
```

However, this approach might depend on the restrictions you have set in place for your account.

**Another option is to deploy your script as a web app**

For deploying a web app, the script should contain a `doGet(e)` or a `doPost(e)` and return a HTML service `HtmlOutput` object or a Content service `TextOutput` object.

After doing this, you should deploy the web app with the following settings:

- Execute as: *Me*
- Who has access: *Anyone within domain*

#### Reference

- [Service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts);
- [Delegate domain-wide authority to your service account](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account);
- [Apps Script Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).